# C++: use SFINAE to detect argument types in Visitor

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I am writing a function that takes a visitor of the form:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(int i) {...}
    void operator()(const std::string& s)  {...}
    void operator()(const auto& s)  {...}
};
```

When my value being visited is a non-const string, I want to detect the const-ness of the visitor function arg. eg if someone passes this visitor:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(const std::string& s)  {...}
    void operator()(const auto& s)  {...}
};
```

or

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(const auto& s)  {...}
};
```

I would like to detect that they will definitely receive a const ref, whereas if they passed:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(std::string& s)  {...}
    void operator()(auto& s)  {...}
};
```

or

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(const std::string& s)  {...}
    void operator()(auto& s)  {...}
};
```

I want to detect that they will be receiving a non-const ref.

I am trying to do this with templates by relying on ambiguous overload errors to detect if the struct contains `operator()` with the particular arg type. For example I can do this (no templates):

```
struct TestConstStringArg {
    void operator()(const std::string& str) {}
};

struct Tester : public TestConstStringArg, public Visitor {
    void tester() {
        std::string s;
        (*this)(s);
    }
};
```

This will give a compile error if `Visitor` also has a `operator(const std::string&)` member, since it will be an ambiguous function resolution.

How can I leverage this in a template to give a `constexpr bool` that I can check? Currently I have this:

```
template <class T, class ArgTest>
struct ArgTester : public T, public ArgTest {
    void tester() {
        std::string s;
        (*this)(s);
    }
};

template<class T>
struct VisitorArgTester {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template<class ArgTest> static no& test(ArgTester<T, ArgTest>* t);
    template<class ArgTest> static yes& test(...);

    static constexpr bool hasConstStr = sizeof(test<TestConstStringArg>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);
};


struct Visitor {
    void operator()(const std::string& str) {}
};
static_assert(VisitorArgTester<Visitor>::hasConstStr);
```

The idea here is that the version of `test()` returning `no&` would compile ok if T did not contain the const string ref arg version, otherwise the ambiguous error would cause the `yes&` version to be used instead. But this does not seem to work, the `static_assert` is always failing whether or not `Visitor` has the operator. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Can't you use `requires` (from C++20)?

Comment: Could you describe what that might look like? I'm struggling to understand the syntax, like how to get true in one case and false in the other

Comment: What if the visitor takes `std::string&` and `std::string`? Would that count as being able to take a `const std::string&` then?

Comment: Why does it matter whether the recipient takes it as const? How would that be different from a non-const parameter that they simply choose not to modify?

Comment: @RaymondChen the internal value is lazy copy-on-write, managed by shared_ptr. If the visitor takes it as const, it is safe to pass a ref the current value directly. If the visitor takes it as non-const, we must assume that the visitor intends to mutate it and therefore must first copy it internally to avoid mutating the shared version.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes that can be treated as const

Comment: Aha, gotcha. So the real question is "Can I give them a read-only reference to my private one, or do I have to give them a copy?" `if constexpr (is_invokable<Visitor, const std::string&>) visitor(static_cast<const std::string&>(*private_shared_ptr)); else { auto temp = *private_shared_ptr; visitor(temp); }`

Comment: @gimmeamilk It looks like all the four visitors are capable of taking a `const std::string&` though. The third one would take it via `auto&` and the fourth via `const std::string&`

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry, to clarify, it's not whether they *can* take a const ref as such, it's more "will the compiler select an overload that is const ref", so for cases 3 and 4, although they can take a const ref if the arg is explicitly that, the non-const versions will be invoked if the arg is a non-const ref or a non-const value

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you! One further thing, is it possible to treat `operator()(auto&)` as always non-const? Currently a visitor containing just that version will be treated as invokable with const ref, but I'd like that one to also perform the private copy

Comment: @gimmeamilk if the visitor _can_ take a `const&` then you can make sure that's the overload it uses by providing a `const&` to it. `std::string my_non_const_str = "..."; const auto& cr = my_non_const_str; visitor(cr);`

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I'm a bit unclear about what you need exactly. The situation also runs deeper than it first appears (longer story). Rather than dissecting your own solution (I know it's what you asked), for now I'm just posting a quick solution of my own at the top of my head that you might be able to use as-is or possibly leverage for your needs (imperfect though still - "static_cast" seen in the solution won't distinguish between noexcept members for instance though that can be handled using more elaborate means if required). I'm not sure if it's even what you're after but first attempt to gauge the situation.

Click [here](https://godbolt.org/z/r7WYfK9Yn) to run it.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename C, typename F>
using FuncToMemberFuncPtr_t = F C::*;

template <typename, typename, typename = void>
struct HasOperator: std::false_type
{
};

template <typename C, typename F>
struct HasOperator<C,
                   F,
                   std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<FuncToMemberFuncPtr_t<C, F>>(&C::operator()))>
                  > : std::true_type
{
};

template <typename C, typename F>
inline constexpr bool HasOperator_v = HasOperator<C, F>::value;

template <typename C>
inline constexpr bool HasOperatorWithNonConstStringRef_v = HasOperator_v<C, void (std::string &) > ||
                                                           HasOperator_v<C, void (std::string &) const>;


template <typename C>
inline constexpr bool HasOperatorWithConstStringRef_v = HasOperator_v<C, void (const std::string &) > ||
                                                        HasOperator_v<C, void (const std::string &) const>;
struct Visitor1
{
    void operator()(int i);
    void operator()(std::string &);
};

struct Visitor2
{
    void operator()(int i);
    void operator()(const std::string &);
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Visitor1 -> void (std::string &): " << std::boolalpha << HasOperatorWithNonConstStringRef_v<Visitor1> << '\n'; // true
    std::cout << "Visitor1 -> void (const std::string &): " << std::boolalpha << HasOperatorWithConstStringRef_v<Visitor1> << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << "Visitor2 -> void (std::string &): " << std::boolalpha << HasOperatorWithNonConstStringRef_v<Visitor2> << '\n'; // false
    std::cout << "Visitor2 -> void (const std::string &): " << std::boolalpha << HasOperatorWithConstStringRef_v<Visitor2> << '\n'; // true

    return 0;
}
```